# Proof that $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf A\mid\mathbf B) = \max(\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf A), \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf B))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

By $(\mathbf A \mid \mathbf B)$, I mean the matrix obtained by adjoining $\mathbf A$ to $\mathbf B$, e.g., if $\mathbf A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\mathbf B = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}6\\7\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then
$$(\mathbf A \mid \mathbf B) = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&6\\
3&4&7
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I have tried to prove it but I don't know how to proceed. Similarly there is the result
$$\operatorname{rank}\left(\frac{\mathbf A}{\mathbf B}\right) = \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf A)+\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf B)$$
which I suspect is proved using a similar technique, but I'm unsure of how to go about it.

Comment: Neither of these is true. E.g. when $A$ and $B$ are two linearly independent vectors, then $\mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{rank}(B) =1$, but $\mathrm{rank} (A|B) = 2$. Similarly, the second statement is false if you take two linearly dependent row vectors.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Are they true under certain conditions? Obviously if $\mathbf B = \mathbf O$, but can it be generalised?

Comment: Sure it can, but the kind of generalization depends on what you're after. Say WLOG $\mathrm{rank}(A) \geq \mathrm{rank}(B)$, then the first statement is true if and only if $\mathrm{im}(B) \subset \mathrm{im}(A)$, where $\mathrm{im}$ denotes the image (sometimes called the "column space")

Comment: I want to use these results as lemmata to obtain that $$\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}\operatorname{rank}\left[\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf A & \mathbf O \\\hline\mathbf B & \mathbf I     \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf I & \mathbf C \\    \hline \mathbf O & \mathbf D \end{array}\right)\right] = \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf A) + \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf D)$$

Comment: That again seems incorrect in general, e.g. when $A=B=C=D=0$ (I assume that you meant to write a vertical bar between the two round parentheses)

Comment: @SebastianSchulz No, this time it is the product of two block matrices :)

Comment: Oh, I see.. what do you know about the sizes of the individual pieces?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Ah yes sorry, I know is that $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf D$ are square and that $\mathbf A$ is invertible, but it feels like we don't need all that for this to be true, do we? Although given the way things are progressing from my original question it seems I have been hasty with my generalisations 

Answer (score 2):

The comments from @Sebastion Schulz show that your conjectures don't stand up.

You don't need any of this to prove
$$
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}\operatorname{rank}\left[\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf A & \mathbf O \\\hline\mathbf B & \mathbf I     \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf I & \mathbf C \\    \hline \mathbf O & \mathbf D \end{array}\right)\right] = \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf A) + \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf D)
$$
when $\mathbf A$ is invertible.

Pre-multiplying by $\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf A & \mathbf O \\\hline\mathbf B & \mathbf I     \end{array}\right)$ in these circumstances is just making some invertible row operations and this does not change the rank of $\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf I & \mathbf C \\    \hline \mathbf O & \mathbf D \end{array}\right)$.

By elementary column operations we can reduce $\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf I & \mathbf C \\    \hline \mathbf O & \mathbf D \end{array}\right)$ to $\left(\begin{array}{c|c}\mathbf I & \mathbf O \\    \hline \mathbf O & \mathbf D \end{array}\right)$, whose rank is $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf I) + \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf D)=\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf A) + \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf D)$.